# Reg. Pandas factorize()

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, data-science-model

-Hi Experts-

I just read about factorise() function in Pandas. Using this I'm able to encode (enumerate) my string values into numbers. But, now I'm not able to understand what  numbers corresponds to what string.

Ex.

```
df['product_name'] # Ex. A, B, C

df['product_name'] = df['product_name'].factorize()[0]
df['product_name'] # Ex. 0, 1, 2
```

Just illustration, not actual o/p -

```
A - 0
B - 1
C - 2
```

How can i get this? Please advise.

-Curious newbie :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documnetation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html)

> Encode the object as an enumerated type or categorical variable.
>
> This method is useful for obtaining a numeric representation of an
>   array when all that matters is identifying distinct values. factorize
>   is available as both a top-level function pandas.factorize(), and as a
>   method Series.factorize() and Index.factorize().

The examples section goes on to show that the output of the `factorize` method actually returns two things:

1. **labels** - referring to the new values for each of your classes
2. **uniques** - essentially the mapping back to your original labels

In your line of code:

```
df['product_name'] = df['product_name'].factorize()[0]
```

The part at the end: `[0]` means you are only taking the `labels`, throwing away the `uniques` that map back to your input.

If you keep both by making the same line:

```
df['product_name'], mapping = df['product_name'].factorize()
```

You could now do the rest of your work and end up with a `results` column full with the factorised output, you can use this line to get the original values back from those factorized labels:

```
mapped_back_to_product_name = mapping.take(results)
```

I suggest reading the documentation to get more information on how best to use the method  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can make use of [categorical dtype in Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

Demo:

Source DF:

```
In [108]: df
Out[108]:
  product_name
0           AA
1           BB
2           AA
3           CC
4           BB
5           AA
```

first convert the string column `product_name` into `category` dtype:

```
In [109]: df['product_name'] = df['product_name'].astype('category')

In [110]: df
Out[110]:
  product_name
0           AA
1           BB
2           AA
3           CC
4           BB
5           AA

In [111]: df.dtypes
Out[111]:
product_name    category
dtype: object
```

now you have access to category codes (encoded numbers):

```
In [113]: df['product_name'].cat.codes
Out[113]:
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    1
5    0
dtype: int8
```

and to categories:

```
In [114]: df['product_name']
Out[114]:
0    AA
1    BB
2    AA
3    CC
4    BB
5    AA
Name: product_name, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [AA, BB, CC]
```

Answer (score 0):

@n1k31t4 has explained well. I just want to add that, by using `sort=True` parameter you can make sure that the labeling is done alphabetically which makes it easy to find out the corresponding labels and factorized classes.

Example from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

> ```
> >>> labels, uniques = pd.factorize(['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'], sort=True)
> >>> labels 
> array([1, 1, 0, 2, 1])
> >>> uniques 
> array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
> ```